# sticky menu con CSS

Tags: php, html, css

Estoy intentado hacer un Sticky menú con puro CSS

He intentado con:

```
position:fixed
top:0px
width:100%
```

y tambien con:

```
position:sticky
top:0px
```

Dando estilos a mi body con:

```
position:flex
flex-direction:columns
align-items:center
```

El menú queda sticky pero el content o body queda encima del menú,
como puedo enviar el body atrás del menú pegajoso?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿has probado z-index?

Comment: Ups, gracias Juan, no lo habia hecho, solucionado.